# I can't assign ArrayList I pulled from Flutter FirebaseFirestore to variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code like this:

```
Array yapilacaklar;

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uID).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    setState(() {
      print("in InitState: " + "${documentSnapshot["yapilacaklar"]}");
      yapilacaklar = documentSnapshot["yapilacaklar"];
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      yapilacaklar = null;
    });
  }
});
```

My goal here is to pull an ArrayList from the Firestore and assign it to the `ArrayList yapilacaklar`'s in the application, which I created as a variable. But I couldn't do it and I couldn't assign it. Is there something wrong with my code?

Full codes:

```
class _appState extends State<app> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var uID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uID).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          print("in InitState: " + "${documentSnapshot["yapilacaklar"]}");
          yapilacaklar = documentSnapshot["yapilacaklar"];
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          yapilacaklar = null;
        });
      }
    });
    print("Yapilacaklar: " + yapilacaklar.toString());
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }
```

Console output:

```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Restarted application in 1.031ms.
I/flutter ( 7369): Yapilacaklar: null
W/DynamiteModule( 7369): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 7369): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 7369): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 7369): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 7369): uid=10146(io.simto.todolist.app) FirestoreWorker identical 1 line
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter ( 7369): in InitState: [Görev 1, Görev 2]
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/flutter ( 7369): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Array<NativeType>'
E/flutter ( 7369): #0      _appState.initState.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter ( 7369): #1      State.setState
E/flutter ( 7369): #2      _appState.initState.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter ( 7369): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 7369): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 7369): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7369):
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 7369): uid=10146(io.simto.todolist.app) FirestoreWorker identical 1 line
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/to.todolist.ap( 7369): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: At the risk of sounding silly, have you tried replacing  yapilacaklar = null; with  yapilacaklar = []; ? We avoid null wherever possible, and use empty lists instead.

Also, you might do well to declare  yapilacaklar  as an empty list and then use the add function to populate it. You could then use  yapilacaklar.clear() to empty it.

Comment: did you forgot convert your snapshot to data? ```final data = documentSnapshot.data();``` and then use ```data["yapilacaklar"]```

Comment: @test Where should I place the codes you gave?

Comment: @EmirBolat right after if doc exists ```if (documentSnapshot.exists) {```